# Create a dabatase from a textfile got an error message in python

Tags: python

I have a  TXT file like these:

| state | sex | year | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AK | F | 1920 | Mary | 14 |
| AK | F | 1920 | Eva | 12 |
| AK | M | 1920 | Ben | 14 |
| AK | M | 1920 | Will | 12 |

I have more than 500'000 rows and it has no header, but the first column is state, the second column is gender, third is year and fourth shows name and fifth shows how many babys were called like this. Now I would like to create a  database with a table. The table is this TXT file. Many names occur more than once  in a column, because it shows how many times in a year this name occurs.

I did it like this:

```
result = open("data/all.TXT", "r")

import sqlite3 as sq3
con = sq3.connect('popular.db')

con.execute('''CREATE TABLE popname  (
               state TEXT, 
               sex TEXT,
               year TEXT,
               forename TEXT
               count INTEGER,
               PRIMARY KEY(forename));''')

for index, row in result.iterrows():
    con.execute('INSERT INTO popname VALUES (?, ?, ?)', row)
con.commit();
con.close();
```

I did that but then it highlights result.iterrows and gave these Error message:

```
'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

The text file has no header, i just add it to make it easier to understand

Comment: What is `all` (besides [built-inPython function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all)) and why do you expect it to have `iterrows()` method?

Comment: all is the TXT file

Comment: But it also don't worked when I used result.TXT and for that I change it to all.TXT

Comment: Can you post the raw contents of the text file without formatting it into a table?

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your code snippet

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I first used result, but got an error message and then I thought I have to use all because of the name of the TXT file

Comment: But still doesn't work

Comment: Can you upload the first few rows from the text file here: https://pastebin.com/ and post the link ?

Comment: File objects have no `iterrows()` method.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can I fix it, I am very frustrated because of that to not find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your text file contains comma separated values:

```
with open("data/all.TXT", "r") as f:
    result = f.readlines()
result = [x.split(",") for x in result]

import sqlite3 as sq3

con = sq3.connect("popular.db")

con.execute(
    """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS popname  (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        state TEXT,
        sex TEXT,
        year TEXT,
        forename TEXT,
        count INTEGER
    );
    """
)

for i, (state, sex, year, forename, count) in enumerate(result):
    con.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO popname VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
        """,
        (i, state, sex, year, forename, count.strip()),
    )
    con.commit()
```

Note that you cannot set `PRIMARY KEY(forename))` since it's very likely some names will repeat and it will violate the `UNIQUE` constraint.

EDIT: I added column `id` and used the row number as value.

Comment: So that it has no header it's not the problem?

Comment: It does not take a header into account, so yeah, no problem.

Comment: I updated the code to add a unique id as primary key.

Comment: is it normal to take to long to create database, since the txt is large?

Comment: It's not the ideal way of importing data from a text file into a database, so yes :)